# Annualized return by group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have monthly return and want to calculate annualized return by two groups. Below is the sample data.

```
Return_M    Rise
0.097425    1
0.188547    1
-0.1509     1
0.28011     1
-0.09596    1
0.041459    1
0.106838    1
0.046581    0
-0.16068    0
0.009242    0
0.006104    0
-0.00709    0
0.050352    0
-0.01023    0
-0.00731    0
0.031946    0
0.048552    0
```

This is what I tried, but the code actually count the length of df1 not by group. I hope a method that could be applied broadly.

`df2 = df1.groupby(['Rise'])[['Return_M']].apply(lambda x:np.prod(1+x)**(12/len(x)))`

This is the expected output:

```
Rise    Return_M
1      0.249862
0      -0.00443
```

Comment: Could you post your expected output?

Comment: I just added the expected output

Answer (score 1):

You only have to `groupby` on `Rise` column and aggregate on the `Return_M` column.

The following snippet assumes you want to divide by 12 (based on your question)

```
df2 = df1.groupby('Rise').agg({'Return_M': 'sum'}).reset_index()

df2['avg'] = df2['Return_M']/12

df2[['Rise', 'avg']]
```

But if you need the average based on however many records you have for each group of `Rise`, you can simply do:

```
df2 = df1.groupby('Rise').agg('Return_M': 'mean')
```

**EDIT**: Editing the answer based on OP's comment:

To get the geometric annualized return as per your formula, the following will work:

```
df.groupby('Rise').Return_M.apply(lambda x: (1+x).product() ** (12/float(len(x))))
```

However, the output is different from the expected output you posted in your question:

```
Rise
0        0.986765
1        1.952498
```

This however is exactly the correct output as per the formula you described.

I did this calculation manually too, for `Rise = 1`:

- I took the product of each (1 plus `Return_M`) value
- Raised the product to (12 divided by length of the group, which is 7 for this group).

`(1 + 0.097425) * (1 + 0.188547) * (1 + -0.1509) * (1 + 0.28011) * (1 + -0.09596)* (1 + 0.041459)* (1 + 0.106838) = 1.4774446702`

`1.4774446702 ^ (12/7) = 1.9524983367`

So just check if your logic is correct. Please mark this answer as accepted if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think it works for the apply method that I have to use in order to calculate the geometric cumulative returns.Your method is to calculate the arithmetic average.

Comment: @Roger I think you should add more details to your question to get a more complete and accurate answer. Can you provide details on how geometric cumulative return is calculated?

Comment: @Roger I have updated my answer to do what you need. You simply group by on the `Rise` column and aggregate the values in `Return_M` column.